# Call to undefined method [package]

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to write a plugin, in a folder with the plugin created composer.json

```
{
  "Require": {
      "Php": "> = 5.4.0",
      "Mattbrown / laracurl": "2.0.0"
   }
}
```

put plugin.php

```
public function boot ()
{
    App :: register ('\ Mattbrown \ Laracurl \ LaracurlServiceProvider');
}
```

But when you call any page happens next interception

```
Call to undefined method [package]
***** / Vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Support /    ServiceProvider.php line 226

# Called Code Document Line

14  Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->__call(…)   ~/plugins/triagmas/parser/vendor/mattbrown/laracurl/src/Mattbrown/Laracurl/LaracurlServiceProvider.php  21
13  Mattbrown\Laracurl\LaracurlServiceProvider->package(…)  ~/plugins/triagmas/parser/vendor/mattbrown/laracurl/src/Mattbrown/Laracurl/LaracurlServiceProvider.php  21
12  Mattbrown\Laracurl\LaracurlServiceProvider->boot()      
11  call_user_func_array(…)     ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php   523
10  Illuminate\Container\Container->call(…)     ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php    703
9   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(…)  ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php    685
8   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(…)       
7   array_walk(…)   ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php    686
6   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()   ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php    15
5   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(…)     ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php    181
4   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(…)     ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php    199
3   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()  ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php    110
2   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(…)  ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php    84
1   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(…)    ~/index.php
```

Please tell me what to do with my mistake

Comment: Doesn't seem like your mistake. Laracurl seems to be incompatible with Laravel 5, because it's using method `package`, which was removed in [Laravel 5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3a0afc20f25ad3bed640ff1a14957f972d123cf7).

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed packet without boot method.

Answer (score -3):

you can find your Answer on this post of ocms forum : http://goo.gl/kXD78r